# How to send data to view from controller on second request?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddl_group").change(function () {
        var grp_id = $("select option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Grpcontroller/GetCheckedPerm',
            data: { usr_groupId: $('#ddl_group').val() },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my controller code.

```
public int GetCheckedPerm(int usr_groupId)
{
    TempData["Hi"] = GrpPermBAL.GetData(usr_groupId);
    return TempData["Hi"];
}
```

This is view

```
int ch = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Hi"].ToString());
```

When dropdown changes i go to controller and write some query and i will get some data. I want that data to be used in view(outside the script). Now i am getting error cannot convert type object to int. How can i do this? i know how to get data inside success block but i want that data to be ouside the script so i am trying to use tempdata

Comment: You ajax specifies `dataType: 'json'` so your method needs to be `public JsonResult GetCheckedPerm(int usr_groupId) { return Json(GrpPermBAL.GetData(usr_groupId);); }`

Comment: Dont convert into toString().

Comment: add `contentType:'application/json'` to your ajax.

Comment: i changed and no error now. But in view i am getting error int ch = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Hi"].ToString()); and the error is near Object reference not set to an instance of an object. when the page loads first time tempdata will be null after changing dropdown we are processing and saving some value in tempdata. How can i solve this?

Comment: You need to remove the `int ch = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Hi"].ToString());` from your view.

Comment: why are you using 'TempData', use normal variable and it will reduce some complex. the error is shown is because the TempData[] is not mapped to any object.

Comment: The return data from controller is in the success event function of ajax. Try show the data of the success event function in the view

Comment: And what do you mean _but i want that data to be outside the script_? How? You you want to update an element in the DOM with the data you return?

Comment: Got it. where i can close this as answered?